# execute validation middleware after validation checks

Tags: javascript, node.js, express-validator

I want to create an Express REST API and want to validate the request params and the request body. If everything is fine I want to call the controller logic.

My validation middleware is

```
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    const validationErrors = req.validationResult();

    if (!validationErrors.isEmpty()) {
        // send a 400
    }

    next();
}
```

and I use it within my routes before calling the controller. This is a snippet of my **topics.js** route file

```
const validation = require('../middleware/validation.js');
const { check } = require('express-validator/check');

router.get('/', topicsController.getAllTopics);

router.get('/:topicId', [
    check('topicId').isUUID()
], validation, topicsController.getTopicById);

router.post('/', authenticationCheck, authorizationCheck, [
    check('parentTopicId').isUUID() || check('parentTopicId').isNull(), // check if it's a UUID. If not, check if it's null
    !check('name').isEmpty(), // is it not empty?
], validation, topicsController.createTopic);

router.put('/:topicId', authenticationCheck, authorizationCheck, [
    check('topicId').isUUID(),
    check('parentTopicId').isUUID() || check('parentTopicId').isNull(),
    !check('name').isEmpty(),
], validation, topicsController.updateTopic);

router.delete('/:topicId', authenticationCheck, authorizationCheck, [
    check('topicId').isUUID()
], validation, topicsController.deleteTopic);
```

I tried to get into it with the docs

https://express-validator.github.io/docs/#basic-guide

but when launching the API I get this error

> Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object
>   Boolean]

So it seems I am not able to pass in an array first, then the validation middleware and then the controller.

Is there a way to fix the route file? I don't want to handle the validation logic within my controller file. I think this should be done before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [oneOf](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/check-api.html#oneofvalidationchains-message) to check for conditional params.

In your routes you use `check('parentTopicId').isUUID() || check('parentTopicId').isNull()` but that returns a boolean and express needs a middleware. `oneOf` was build especially for this.

Also you should replace `!check` with `check('name').not().isEmpty()`.

Comment: thanks for your help. I updated it to https://pastebin.com/scNKnHNy but this didn't fix it

Comment: you are also using !check.isEmpty() you should be using check.not().isEmpty()

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to check if something is `null`? Because `isNull` is not a function too :(

Comment: so I don't want to check if a variable is empty, I really need to check if it's null

Comment: yes, if you are using express validator >= 5.3.0 you can use .exists and use the option checkNull. https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html#existsoptions

Comment: so I could go for `.exists({ checkNull: true })`?